# get css() property before append()?

Tags: jquery

how can you get a css property before the element is appended?

css

```
input.inp {
    padding:3px 2px 3px 2px;
}
```

js

```
var elm = $('<input class="inp" type="text" />');

alert(elm.css('padding-left'));
td.append(elm);
alert(elm.css('padding-left'));
```

only the second alert retuns the value...

I want the input element to have width:100%.. but since you can't do that (when the input has a padding of its own) I need to set the width in pixels

1. get width of the the TD where the INPUT has to be appended...
2. get the left and right padding of the INPUT
3. append the INPUT to the TD with the width of the TD minus the left and right padding of the INPUT

Comment: Hi, may I know what's the scope of knowing a padding before the el. is appended? if you explain your idea or needs we can help find a workaround.

Comment: I still don't understand.... try create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You cant get the css properties or and values of something that doesn't not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could insert a hidden input, with the class, get the css properties and the use them.

```
<input id="getPadding" class="inp" type="text" style="display:none" />
```

Then after the element is appended You can just get the elements parent width and then set the input to that width minus the amount of padding.. Like so

```
 $('td input').width($(this).parent().width() - [$('#getPadding').css('padding-left') + $('#getPadding').css('padding-right')])
```

Alternatively there is a css only solution but it does not work in IE7 and below

```
td input {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: don't you know what the padding is? its really simple to get it in the script if you need to

Comment: please show me.. how can you get the padding of an element before it is appended? or how can you get it directly from the stylesheet

Comment: You cant get the css properties or and values of something that doesn't not exist.

Comment: updated, should cover what you are trying to do in 2 different methods

Answer (score 2):

If it's not in the DOM, then you can't, AFAIK.

Comment: how can you then get the property from the stylesheet?

Comment: I thought it was added to the DOM as you created the elm with $() in the first line?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the padding is in a style sheet, and it depends on the position in the document which css applies to the element. So when the element is not in place, it doesn't have that styles yet. 
It has to be part of the DOM at least, and (depending on the css selectors) the exact position in the DOM may matter too.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
$('<input class="inp" type="text" />');
```

Is the same as doing:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.className = "inp";
```

And in both these cases they return a Detached element.

As the element hasn't been appended to the `DOM` yet the `class` doesn't take affect so the no `Css` is applied to the element.

So when you try to get the padding it won't be set.

You would have to add the padding inline to able to get it before you add it to the `DOM`

```
$('<input class="inp" type="text" />').css("padding", "5px");
```

Comment: how can you then get the padding before the element is appended?

Comment: You would have to add the padding inline before its added to the DOM.

Comment: and what do you mean by that?

Answer (score -1):

```
var padbefore = $("elmid").css('padding-left');
alert(padbefore);
$("td").append('elmid');
var paddafter = $("elmid").css('padding-left');
alert(paddafter);
```